# Find Percentage of Male and Female

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

After the below code i was able to get the count from the data set:

```
Users2 = Users.gender.groupby([Users['occupation'],Users['gender']]).count().astype(int)
Users2
```

Output:

```
occupation     gender
administrator  F          36
               M          43
artist         F          13
               M          15
doctor         M           7
educator       F          26
               M          69
engineer       F           2
               M          65
```

However instead of count i need the percentage of Male and Female.

Sample Data:

```
user_id age gender  occupation
0   1   24    M     doctor
1   2   53    F     educator
2   3   23    M     writer
3   4   24    M     administrator
4   5   33    F     artist
```

Comment: ur sample data does not contain administrator or engineer or doctor or educator.

Comment: Can you add expected output `DataFrame` from `Sample Data` ?

Comment: Those are just more than 200 categories

Comment: here i will edit it for understanding, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with `normalize=True`:

```
#changed sample data for better MCVE
print (Users)
   user_id  age gender  occupation
0        1   24      M  technician
1        2   53      F  technician
2        3   23      M      writer
3        4   24      M  technician
4        5   33      F      writer

df = (Users.groupby('occupation')['gender']
           .value_counts(normalize=True)
           .reset_index(name='perc'))
print (df)
   occupation gender      perc
0  technician      M  0.666667
1  technician      F  0.333333
2      writer      F  0.500000
3      writer      M  0.500000
```

Details:

```
#without normalize=True get counts per groups
print (Users.groupby('occupation')['gender']
             .value_counts())
occupation  gender
technician  M         2
            F         1
writer      F         1
            M         1
Name: gender, dtype: int64

#with normalize=True get percentages
print (Users.groupby('occupation')['gender']
             .value_counts(normalize=True))

occupation  gender
technician  M         0.666667
            F         0.333333
writer      F         0.500000
            M         0.500000
Name: gender, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Can you also suggest how resetting the Index makes the percentage appear?.reset_index(name='perc')

Comment: @DhruvNautiyal - `.reset_index(name='perc')` not working?

Comment: @DhruvNautiyal - Or you need different output?

Comment: yes it is working, all i want is just an explanation to understand how .reset_index(name='perc') is calculating the percentage.

Comment: @DhruvNautiyal - I got you. It is different, percentages are count in `value_counts(normalize=True)`. `.reset_index(name='perc')` is used for convert `Series` to `DataFrame`. You can test it by `print ((Users.groupby('occupation')['gender']
           .value_counts(normalize=True)))`

Comment: So does this means value_counts(normalize=True) will give counts for series and when converted to DataFrame by .reset_index(name='perc') will give percentage?

Comment: @DhruvNautiyal - No, it count percentages for `Series with MultiIndex`, `.reset_index` here is used for converting format.